# manga about when fmc skin touched by opposite gender will show animal ear and tail

Tags: story-identification, manga

The story is in high school. In a class, the main character sees a beautiful female classmate who is shy and did not want to be close to male classmates. The female classmate has a sister or cousin. The female classmate's house is some shrine or something. The main character went to the female classmate's house. In the house the main character accidentally touched the female classmate hand. After that the body female classmate change, and she has animal ears and hair.

Comment: This makes me think of a genderswapped version of *Fruits Basket*.

Comment: Was this in full color or black and white? About what year did you read this?

Comment: black and white, i think 3 years ago, maybe 2020 from raw site because it still in japanese language.